# About a symbol $[ \ , L|K] : I_{K} \to G(L|K)$ (Algebraic Number Theory )

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'am reading Jurgen Nueukirch's Algebraic number theory, p.387

[image]

I'm trying to understand the underlined statements (Here, $I_K$ is the idele group of $K$ (his book p.357) and ($\alpha _\mathfrak{p}, L_{\mathfrak{p}}|K_{\mathfrak{p}})$ is the local norm residue symbol (his book p.321))

Q.1) What does 'the completion $L_{p}$ with respect to $\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p}$' means?
What $\mathfrak{P}$ here means?

Q.2) Second, why almost all extensions $L_{p} | K_{p}$ are unramified? And how can we deduce that almost all factors in the product are $1$?

Comment: If $K$ is a number field and $v$ is a place, you can consider that $v$ (or $e^{-v}$ or some power of either) is a metric on $K$. The completion of $K$ wrt $v$ is simply the completion of $K$ as a metric space. It is a topological field with many good properties. In this case, $\mathfrak{P}$ is a place of $L$ extending the place $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ and you consider the completion of $L$ at said place. Its algebraic/topological structure doesn’t depend much on the choice of $\mathfrak{P}$ if $L/K$ is Galois because then the group acts transitively on the places of $L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: (Cont’d) [place=equivalence class of nontrivial absolute values] for your second question, $L_p/K_p$ is unramified iff $L/K$ is unramified at $\mathfrak{P}$, which occurs at finitely many $\mathfrak{P}$ (use the discriminant, for instance). The last part is because the reciprocity symbol for local fields (or whatever Neukirch calls it) vanishes on the elements of the base fields that are norms, and because, for an unramified extension of local fields, every unit is a norm.

Comment: Uhm. I trying to follow your comment. First, $\mathfrak{P}$ is arbitrary place extending $\mathfrak{p}$? And you said that "its algebraic/topological structure doesn’t depend much on the choice of $\mathfrak{P}$ if $L/K$ is Galois because then the group acts transitively on the places of $L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$" How this facts affects the formula for $[    , L|K]$ as product? Such a definition is really independent to $\mathfrak{P}$?

Comment: Second, you said that $L_{\mathfrak{p}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}$  is unramified iff $L/K$ is unramified at $\mathfrak{P}$, which occurs at finitely many $\mathfrak{P}$. But correctly, "all but finitely many $\mathfrak{P}$", instead of " occurs at finitely many $\mathfrak{P}"? Any why this equivalence is true? Where can I find associated information?

Comment: Third, as you noted, the local norm residue symbol(Neukirch's book, p.321) $(  \ , L|K) : K^{\ast} \to G(L|K)^{ab}$ has kernel $N_{L|K} L^{\ast}$. So key point is showing that every unit in the ring $\mathcal{O}$ of integers of $K$ is contained in $N_{L|K} L^{\ast}$.

Comment: Anyway, I'll try to fill up your comment, Thanks.

Comment: 1. Yes – all choices of $\mathfrak{P}$ extending $\mathfrak{p}$ will give the same result. The point is that the local/global symbol $(\cdot, E/F)$ depends only on $F$ and the abstract extension $E/F$. 2. Yes, it’s “all but finitely many”. Thanks for correcting. I expect that Neukirch’s ANT (or any other text, really) contains all that standard stuff in the earlier chapters. 3. Yes. It’s not entirely trivial but it’s overall doable.